# Como limpar ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

Como limpar uma `ListBox`?

Fiz destas formas mas não funcionaram:

```
private void LimparListBox()
{
    //lbxResumo.Text = "";
    lbxResumo.ClearSelected();
}

private void btnLimparList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LimparListBox();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa `Items.Clear()` para limpar o textbox.

Exemplo:

```
private void LimparListBox()
{
    //lbxResumo.Text = "";
    lbxResumo.Items.Clear();
}

private void btnLimparList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LimparListBox();
}
```

Fonte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms228375(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

O comando correto seria:

```
List.Items.Clear
```

Coloque o nome do seu ListBox no lugar de List

O exemplo que você usou:

```
lbxResumo.ClearSelected();
```

limpa apenas o item selecionado.